# Teste de normalidade para amostra de 12 a 15 mil observações - R

Tags: r

Alguém conhece um teste de normalidade que pode ser estimado (no R) para amostras entre 12 a 15 mil observações?

O shapiro.test deve ter tamanho de amostra entre 3 e 5000, não se aplica a minha amostra.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [Anderson-Darling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test#Test_for_normality)

Instale o pacote `nortest` e rode:

```
library(nortest)
ad.test(rnorm(5001))

#   Anderson-Darling normality test
#
# data:  rnorm(5001)
# A = 0.2826, p-value = 0.6359

ad.test(runif(5001))

#   Anderson-Darling normality test
#
# data:  runif(5001)
# A = 65.183, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781798/seeing-if-data-is-normally-distributed-in-r/7788452#7788452) tem uma boa explicação do porque existem limitações com relação ao tamanho da amostra. E também opiniões fortes do porque não usar esses testes.

Comment: Obrigada, Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que existem criticas a inspeção de normalidade usando testes formais, uma alternativa é fazer inspeção gráfica por meio de histograma e ver se ocorre a forma de sino na figura resultante. O comando hist(dados) faz isso. Busque imagens de histogramas distribuição normal e os use de referência. Se o seu histograma não tiver forma de sino, tente transformações nos dados e refaça o histograma.